# Example of a Regular Map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, regular-expressions

I am working with Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry 1".

> Example 1.15: The map $f(t)=(t^2,t^3)$ is a regular map on the line $\mathbb{A}^1$ to the curve given by $y^2=x^3$.

I am not familiar with regular functions yet, so I have some problems to see how this works.
So $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to V(y^2-x^3)$. But why do we see this out of $f(t)=(t^2,t^3)$? Because not all $t\in\mathbb{A}^1$ would fulfill $y^2-x^3=0$ or how is it meant? 

I hope you understand where my problem is.. I would be happy for any further explanation of this example! Thanks and best, Luca

Comment: You're thinking inverting x with y. $t^6 = t^6$ always

Comment: Sorry... I don't know how you mean that. I am quite blocked here.

Comment: Just substitute the equation for x and y. You are putting the first coordinate in y and vice versa

Comment: The proof that $f$ is a regular map with values in $ V(y^2-x^3)$ is that the equality $(t^3)^2-(t^2)^3=0$ is valid for all $t\in \mathbb A^1$.

Comment: Uh, ok! I think I got it now :)
You can put it as an answer if you like, and I'll accept.